# Applying CSS3 to PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, jquery, css, dom, domdocument

I'm trying to apply CSS to a DOMDocument created through PHP. However, even when I use jQuery to apply the styles, it doesn't work. Here's an example I have:

```
<div id="content">
<p class="intro">Below are some of the YouTube videos I've made.
    <br />Feel free to take a look!</p>
<div id="video-content">
    <?php include '../resources/php/functions.php';
            $functions=new Functions;
            $functions->getVideos();
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('iframe-video').css({
                "margin-left": "auto"
            });
            $('iframe-video').css({
                "margin-right": "auto"
            });
            $('iframe-video').css({
                "margin-bottom": "35px"
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

The `$functions->getVideos();` successfully returns the videos, and they are displayed. They are also given the iframe-video class. However, the above CSS doesn't actually apply to it.

How can I change the CSS of elements generated by PHP DOMDocument?

PHP code is as follows:

```
public function getVideos() {
        $doc = new DOMDocument;
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.youtube.com/user/HathorArts/videos');
        libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

        $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
        $nodes = $xpath -> query('//a[@class="ux-thumb-wrap yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-contextlink yt-fluid-thumb-link contains-addto "]');

        // Get the URLS for the videos, and build the iFrames for them.
        $output = new DOMDocument;
        foreach($nodes as $i => $node) {
            // Creates the video URL for the iFrame
            $temp_url = $node->getAttribute('href');
            $replace_url = str_replace("/watch?v=", "", $temp_url);
            $video_url = ("//www.youtube.com/embed/" . $replace_url . "?rel=0");

            // Builds the iFrme
            $iframe = $output->createElement('iframe');
            $iframe->setAttribute('class', 'iframe-video');
            $iframe->setAttribute('width', '560');
            $iframe->setAttribute('height', '315');
            $iframe->setAttribute('src', $video_url);
            $iframe->setAttribute('frameborder', "0");

            // Outputs the iFrame
            $output->appendChild($iframe);
        }

        // Sends the output to the index file
        echo $output -> saveHTML();
    }
```

Comment: `$('iframe-video')` should be `$('.iframe-video')` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a CSS file, just add properties for `.iframe-video`. PHP has nothing to do with CSS, only the HTML output.

Comment: With this, the margin-bottom works, but the margin-left and margin:right auto; doesn't work.

Comment: I was able to find a work-around to using those styles specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Change a few lines in your script code; then it will work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.iframe-video').css({
            "margin-left": "auto"
        });
        $('.iframe-video').css({
            "margin-right": "auto"
        });
        $('.iframe-video').css({
            "margin-bottom": "35px"
        });
    });
</script>
```

This will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

You should delay the JavaScript code after the page load like this:

```
window.onload = function () { ... }
```